# Google Analytics API returning 403 rate limit but we are well under the rate

Tags: ruby, google-analytics, google-oauth

We daily download data from Google Analytics API. This morning, a number of jobs on one of our accounts hit a 403 "Serving Limit Exceeded" error. However, I checked into the statistics posted in the console and our records don't appear to be anywhere near the limit.

- We made 335 requests this morning. This is far less than the 50k daily requests limit.
- The API Chart on our console page shows that we peaked at 0.1322 requests/second which is much lower than the limit I've read being about 10 requests/second.
- We run at most two simultaneous processes from each of two IP addresses; these have a five second delay between jobs and the jobs make only one request each.
- Those 335 requests are spread across four different GA accounts, although they are likely queued such that all request for a single account are contiguous.
- The errors occurred between midnight and 6AM Pacific time (-0700).
- When I re-ran all the jobs at 8AM Pacific time they ran without error.

I'm I missing something in the rate limiting? Can someone explain what factor would cause us to hit this limit?

We're using the [`google-api-client`](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) gem.

Comment: Hm, is it reproducible locally? If so, did you try debugging the response in that gem if there is more info available in the request response?

Comment: Unfortunately, not reproducible at all. As I mentioned, I re-ran the jobs after a two-hour delay and they completed just fine. I recognize that one-off problems are hard to solve; I was hoping for any information that we could use to tune our process to maintain compliance with the rate limiting guidelines.